Is there a 2d shape that can be decomposed into 3 2d shapes each similar to the original, and such that any 2 of the smaller shapes also are similar?
Does there exist a two dimensional shape that can be decomposed into three smaller shapes such that

each of the smaller shapes is similar to the original shape
the union of any two of the smaller shapes is also similar to the original shape?


Yes - when a right triangle is rotated to lie on its hypotenuse and the altitude is drawn, the new right triangles it's split into are similar to both the original right triangle and each other.

Draw an altitude from the vertex with the marked right angle to either of the original triangle's legs to split the original triangle into 3 smaller, similar triangles.

Hi, while this does result in 3 triangles all similar to the original, the union of any two of the small triangles is not similar to the original triangle, which was another thing that I required. To be clear, I want a single tripartitioning such each of the tripartioned regions is similar to the unpartitioned region, and the union of each pair of the tripartitioned regions is also similar to the unpartitioned region.
